# Laravel, query to show big data is slow

Tags: sql, laravel, performance, datatable

I have a page for user searching data from specific date range and it will show result in datatable e.g (`ID`, `Audit type`, `user`, `new value`, `old value` etc.) and it was from 2 table relationship.

Here is my query:

```
$audits = \OwenIt\Auditing\Models\Audit::with('user')
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
    ->where('created_at', '>=', $date1)
    ->where('created_at', '<=', $date2)
    ->get;
```

The problem is if amount of data is big, the process so slow. How to optimize the query?

I've tried to use `paginate(10)` or `take(10)`, but it only show 10 data not all data.

Answer (score 0):

To enhance performance at database level, create an index on the column which appears in where constraints.

So create an index on the `created_at` column.

Also to compare dates, why not use the `whereDate` rather than comparing string literals for dates

```php
$audits = \OwenIt\Auditing\Models\Audit::with('user')
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
    ->whereDate('created_at','>=',$date1)
    ->whereDate('created_at','<=',$date2)
    ->paginate(25);
```

Once the query is getting paginated records, the view can then provide the pagination links for the visitors/users to loop through the paginated result sets

```
{{ $audit->links() }}
```

The `links()` will insert pagination link buttons on the view, which users/visitors can click to shuffle through the result sets.

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

For large datasets/records in database tables, its always wise to query paginated result sets - to reduce memory usage.